# Defining Conflicting Modules in Julia

Tags: scikit-learn, julia, xgboost

I am new to Julia (used with MATLAB).  I am taking some datasets, cleaning it and encoding categorical variable using tools that are available in ScikitLearn then running XGBoost of the clean data.

However, I cannot make a prediction using by trained XGBoost model because both ScitkitLearn and XGBoost have a function named `predict`. Refer to the error message below:

> WARNING: both ScikitLearn and XGBoost export "predict"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
>   ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: predict not defined

The problem is that I can not define the `predict` function for XGBoost as `XGBoost.predict` because this does not work and it seems to be the only solution that I know of.

Further, I cannot find or understand how I can load only specific modules from ScikitLearn without loading the predict function. e.g, the format `import MLDataUtils.splitobs` works for most packages but `ScikitLearn.preprocessing` does not work.

Comment: You can do `import name_of_package: name_of_function_you_want, 2nd_function_you_want` I believe. Someone check me on this.

Comment: @logankilpatrick, you can, but the error that was posted should not occur nevertheless.  @ForzaRS, could you give the stacktrace?  From what I can see, it seems like there was a function defined in your current working module which used `predict`.

Comment: Hi  @AnshulSinghvi 

Thanks for the response. 

Here is the stacktrace

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: predict not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /Users/sinkala/Documents/MATLAB/Dream Challenge Breast Cancer Network/rescaleScript.jl:92

Comment: Thanks @logankilpatrick

I have tried "import ScikitLearn:Preprocessing,LabelEncoder" , and I get the error below

WARNING: could not import ScikitLearn.LabelEncoder into Main

Within Julia, the code below works fine

using ScikitLearn: fit_transform!

Also, I have found that the format that you suggested works for almost anything else but for the LabelEncoder. i.e., 

using ScikitLearn:LabelEncoder
import ScikitLearn:LabelEncoder

Does not work. :(

*What I am missing?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE of your problem (two modules `export`ing the same name):

```
module A
    export f
    f() = println("f from A")
end
module B
    export f
    f() = println("f from B")
end
```

Now, consider the situation where you `using` both `A` and `B` and try to call `f`:

```
julia> using .A, .B

julia> f()
WARNING: both B and A export "f"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
ERROR: UndefVarError: f not defined
```

The reason this fails is that Julia does not know what you mean with `f`; is it `A.f` or `B.f`? You can solve this problem by explicitly disambiguating the any call to `f`:

```
julia> using .A, .B

julia> A.f()
f from A

julia> B.f()
f from B
```

If you want to be able to call one of the functions by name alone (`f`) then you (the user) have to choose what `f` should point to. You can do this by explicitly defining that as part of the import statement:

```
julia> using .A, .B

julia> using .B: f # explicitly choosing f to be B.f

julia> f() # no error
f from B

julia> A.f()
f from A

julia> B.f()
f from B
```

Another alternative is to just explicitly define your own name `f` in your namespace:

```
julia> using .A, .B

julia> const f = B.f # defining a new name in this namespace pointing to B.f
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f() # no error
f from B

julia> A.f()
f from A

julia> B.f()
f from B
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do things the other round. 
Only importing what I need from ScikitLearn. Which seems to have some bugs at the moment. 

Therefore, I simply specified the predict function as per your example: 

**using XGBoost
using XGBoost:predict**

And it took care of all my ScikitLearn problems